# How generate a table with right values with jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, jspdf

In my project I don't know how to include a table in my pdf when it is generated.
The version of my jsPDF is 1.2.61 with jQuery 1.12.4

This is my code:

```
<table id="tablePDF">
<tr><td>Value1a</td><td>Value2b</td><td>Value3c</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value1a</td><td>Value2b</td><td>Value3c</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value1a</td><td>Value2b</td><td>Value3c</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value1a</td><td>Value2b</td><td>Value3c</td></tr>
</table>

<button id="downloadPDF" onclick="generatePDF()">DOWNLOAD PDF</button>

<script>
function generatePDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  
  doc.fromHTML($('#tablePDF').html(), 20,20, {
    'width':500
  });
  
  doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
</script>
```

The content of my div I would like to include in the pdf as a table.

**Example:**
If I have a table in my html with 4 rows I would like all 4 to be reported. If there are 10 rows and the table goes beyond the sheet boundary then add a new page.

This I tried to do with the pdf.fromHTML function but I can't use it because it sets times new roman as default font and I want the arial as font.

How can I do to achieve this in the pdf?